# ios URLSessionDataTask use resume with Data

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessiondatatask, urlsession

I'am using  `URLSessionDataTask` to download videos and play them (I need caching so I'am using the

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
```

to manually handle the data and provide them to `AVAssetResourceLoader` ).

in order to do disk caching I must save the downloaded data to disk (when terminating the app) , so that when the user open the app again I can continue downloading the data .

I noticed that it doesn't have a `downloadTask(withResumeData:)` like constructor (constructor of `URLSessionDownloadTask` which pretty much does that same think , but it doesn't have the `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)` function :D ) .
now how can I combine these two ?
thank you and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Range` header in the request. But you may use it only if the server informs you that it accept range request by `Accept-Ranges` response header.
So, if server supports loading from offset You need to add downloaded part offset as header when creating `URLRequest`

For more info see the [Range header specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) in HTTP RFC 2616.

Comment: @user3703910, how did you do it. can i see the code. Thanks

Comment: request.setValue("bytes=\(dataLength)-", forHTTPHeaderField: "Range")